# Javascript stop push when unique value occur

Tags: javascript, arrays, count, 2d, unique

I populate a 2d array with a while loop, but I need to stop the push when the 1st column contains 3 different unique value.

the start is something like this

```
var maxunique;
var i = 0;

while (countunique(arr) != maxunique) {

    // my code that push data into array
    arr[i].push(RandomNumber(1,8));
    arr[i].push(i+1);
i++;
}


function countunique(arr)
{
    // function here
}

function RandomNumber(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
```

This return that value

```
arr:  [ [ 4, 1 ],
  [ 7, 2 ],
  [ 5, 3 ],
  [ 5, 4 ],
  [ 3, 5 ],
  [ 1, 6 ],
  [ 7, 7 ],
  [ 8, 8 ],
  [ 5, 9 ],
  [ 5, 10 ] ]
```

Whell the idea about the expected result is

```
arr:  [ [ 4, 1 ],
  [ 7, 2 ],
  [ 5, 3 ] ]
```

you can see that the push is interrupted after the first 5, that is the 3 unique value in array

I don't know how to do it, and I don't know if is better do to with a while or a for loop.

Any Idea?

Comment: `for(...) { if (already at unique item limit) { don't push } } `, basically.

Comment: Hehehe I don't know how to check this strange condition

Comment: so write some code to count how many of item X you have in the array, and DON'T push if it's over thel imit.

Comment: Create an object whose keys are the values you want to be unique. When you push a value, also add it to the object. Then get the length of `Object.keys(yourObject)` to find out how many unique values there are. When you reach the limit, break out of the loop.

Comment: In ES6 you can use a Set, which might be slightly more convenient.

Comment: the problem is that don't know the exact length before I start to push

Answer (score 1):

In the loop where you are populating the 2D array, have the array sent to a check function that determines if 3 unique elements are present as the first elements in the individual array. Here is the code for check function, it returns true if 3 unique elements are not yet present, once it finds 3 unique elements it returns false.

```
var a = []; //; 
var i = 0;
while (check(a)) {
  a[i]=[];
  a[i].push(RandomNumber(1, 42));
  a[i].push(i + 1);
  i++;
}

function RandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function check(arr) {
  var length = arr.length;
  var tmp = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < length; j++) {
    if (tmp.indexOf(arr[j][0]) === -1) {
      tmp.push(arr[j][0]);
    }
    if (tmp.length === 3) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
console.log('test: ', a);
console.log('check: ', check(a));
```

Comment: I update the 1st question. In that way I only need if the check is false! But I need to put in a while loop

Comment: I tried to implement the solution on a simple code, maybe I miss something the next contain the code

Comment: var a = new Array(4); // For example 5;
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i] = [];
}

var i = 0;
while (check(a) === true) {
 a[i].push(RandomNumber(1,42));
 a[i].push(i+1);
 i++;
}

function RandomNumber(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

function check(arr){
var length=  arr.length;
var tmp=[];
for(var j=0;j<length;j++){
 if(tmp.indexOf(arr[j][0])===-1){
   tmp.push(arr[j][0]);
 }
 if(tmp.length === 3){
  return false;
 }
}
return true;
}

console.log('test: ',a);
console.log('check: ',check(a));

Comment: @Jorman Franzini, I have modified the code that you put in the comments section. The full working code is in the post.

Answer (score 0):

This implements a real push:

```
var yourarray={
   arr:[],
   push:function(obj){
     for(a=0;a<this.obj.length){
     let count=0;
       for(i=0;i<this.arr.length;i++){
          if(obj[a]!=this.arr[i][a]){
             count++;
             if(count==3){
                break;
             }
          }
        }
      }
     this.arr.push(obj);      
    };
 };
```

Now you can do:

```
yourarray.push([0,1,2]);
```

And access it like:

```
alert(yourarray.arr);
```

However, accessing yourarray directly isnt possible anymore

Comment: Erm, some problems here: 1. The `arr` property is _an object_ and the `obj` parameter is _an array_. 2. This code also throws a `SyntaxError` and 3. I don't thing it would work even if it was not there because it tries to read `arr.length` which a) does not exist, I assume you mean `this.arr` b) even then it's _an object_, so it doesn't have a `length` property. EDIT: oh, and I somehow forgot 4. atrocious formatting.

Comment: @vlaz: sorry. Edited

Answer (score 0):

You could use one object to store each first number as property and check in each iteration of `while` loop if any value in that object is equal 3. If it is you can break from loop. I used random number for first number.

```js
var ar = [];
var obj = {}

while (true) {
  var firstNum = parseInt(Math.random() * 5) + 1;

  ar.push([firstNum, 1]);
  obj[firstNum] = (obj[firstNum] || 0) + 1;

  var stop = Object.keys(obj).find(function(e) {
    return obj[e] == 3;
  });
  if (stop) break;
}

console.log(obj);
console.log(ar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a function which stores the number of the first column as a property in a object and increments a counter if that number does not exist in that object.If the counter is equal to 3 then there are 3 unique elements,then stop the array push and break out of the loop.

Here is an example code.

```
var arr =   ['-15, 1',
'-15, 2' ,
'2,3' ,
'2, 4' ,
'2, 5',
'77, 6','22,3'  ];

function unique(array) {
var arr = [],x,y,obj = {},count = 0,arr1;
for (i = 0; i < array.length ; i++) {
    arr1 = array[i].split(',');
    x = arr1[0] * 1;
    y = arr1[1] * 1;

    if (count === 3) {
        break;
    }

    array.push([x,y]);


    if (!obj[x]) {
        obj[x] = 1;
        count++;
    }

}
}
```